# Is it possible to execute an INSERT statement using dynamically populated variable names?

Tags: sql, plsql

suppose we have a table:  MASTER_X_Y in the database.

I want the syntax to run the query :

```
INSERT INTO MASTER_VARIABLE1_VARIABLE2 VALUES (.....);
```

where VARIABLE1 and VARIABLE2 have values X and Y respectively which have been selected from another table.

Is this possible ?
( I have 38 possible combinations of X and Y and simply want to insert the selected data into the correct tables. Is there any other approach ? )

I am using oracle SQL 11g.
This is the first time I am writing a PL/SQL procedure and I am not getting any straightforward answers.

Thank you !

Comment: There's a documentation section titled [PL/SQL Dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011). I know it's too late for the comment to be constructive but I have the impression that you should only have a single `MASTER` table with two (indexed) columns for the variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is , try this:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO MASTER_' || t.x || '_' || t.y || ' VALUES(...);'
FROM YourTable t
```

And then execute the output .

Comment: Don't forget to test the `'MASTER_'||t.x||'_'||t.y` table name using [dbms_assert.sql_object_name](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2#SQL_OBJECT_NAME) to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Yes , although it's unlikely that these kind of tables will be harmed, it's best to make sure you are protected from it at all time. @Boneist

Comment: Is it somehow possible to just populate the table name and avoid the execute immediate the string ? like

    SELECT * FROM var_table_name
    WHERE col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'b';

Answer (score 0):

Add a varchar variable v_sql_stmt in the declare section, prepare the statement as below and then execute immediate dynamically.

v_sql_stmt:='INSERT INTO MASTER'||'*'||VARIABLE1||'*'||VARIABLE2||' VALUES (.....)';

execute immediate v_sql_stmt;